# Solving vehicle routing problem in java

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve vehicle routing problem in java and I am looking for libraries for the same. I did a POC using google or-tools and it seems to be solving all my use cases. I would like to know if anyone in the community has used OR-tools libraries in production and if yes, what are the problems I have to look out for ?

If not google or-tools, what are the other VRP java libraries you are using and how was your experience using them in production ? I am particularly interested in jsprit/ Optaplanner/or-tools etc., w.r.t ease of use, maintainability (when new constraints have to be added) and the performance in production.

Thanks

Comment: Traffic on or.stackexchange is low. You will have more chances to get an answer if you ask on the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/or-tools-discuss

Comment: Would you try googling your issue? There are many software/framework which using Java to solve the VRP variants problems. E.g. [this](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/vehicleRoutingProblem.html), [this](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit), [this](https://www.localsolver.com/docs/last/exampletour/vrp.html) and [this](https://www.localsolver.com/docs/last/exampletour/vrp.html) links. I hope they would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

*I am obviously biased*, but if you're looking to do VRP in a Java environment, do take a look at [this guide for OptaPlanner that builds a JSON REST service for school timetabling from scratch](https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner). It supports logging, database integration and native compilation (yes, Java does that now). In general, OptaPlanner works with Maven or Gradle - Java, Kotlin or Scala - Quarkus or Spring Boot - JDK HotSpot or GraalVM: it's all good.

OptaPlanner is heavily used for [the Vehicle Routing Problem](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/vehicleRoutingProblem.html), including Fortune 500 customers, such as cases with tens of thousands of vehicles that privately benchmarked it against 3 other implementations (including Google OR tools) and found OptaPlanner had the best results. *Your mileage may vary, of course.* Especially if you don't powertweak it. We should do open, independent benchmarks between vendors to confirm this and give each vendor a chance to tweak their stuff (private benchmarks aren't fair). Do note that it's a very different philosophy (OO+FP) than traditional solvers (math equations).

To get started with VRP, take a look at `optaplanner-examples` which has a VRP example and `optaweb-vehicle-routing` which has OpenStreetMap integration.

Comment: I extracted the zip file of the optaweb after downloading it from Github, I am trying to run optaweb but it is giving me an error ( Cannot resolve symbol 'DepotAngleVisitDifficultyWeightFactory') 'org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.weight.DepotAngleVisitDifficultyWeightFactory' is imported but the console says that the library is not used ...... Any idea ?

Comment: It has some trouble recently. I know this simplified quickstarts version works out-of-the-box, but it can use severe optimization config wise: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing#vehicle-routing-problem-java-quarkus-maven

Comment: this quickstart worked, it showed a map of 2 depots and customers in an italian city... I want this to run for 4 depots and greater number of customers, what should i do exactly ??

Comment: Adjust the demo generating code which you can find here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing/src/main/java/org/acme/vehiclerouting/bootstrap

Comment: I have a dataset of 145 customer and 4 depots with their location Lat&Long Coordinates and a demand for each customer.... I want to import this to the model, what source code I should use for this purpose ?.. The demo contains a randomly generated list of customers not an imported dataset